# Adding css shape to datatables pagination

Tags: css, database

I have a table that is created with datatables plugin,I want to add css shape to the pagination of my datatables without using datatables css plugin.I have removed previous and next text with '<' and '>' and I need to add triangle facing towards left  instead of '<' and again I need to add triangle facing towards right instead of '>'.I tried but triangle is cutting towards left and right.Here is the code below.Thanks in advance

### HTML

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<div id="div">
<div>
     <table id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Seq.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>



            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>55</td>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>50</td>
                    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>2010/10/14</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>26</td>
                    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2009/09/15</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2008/12/13</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>13</td>
                    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2008/12/19</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2008/10/16</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2012/12/18</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>54</td>
                    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2010/03/17</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>Michael Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2012/11/27</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>32</td>
                    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2010/06/09</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>Gloria Little</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2009/04/10</td>
                    <td>$237,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>48</td>
                    <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2012/10/13</td>
                    <td>$132,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>45</td>
                    <td>Dai Rios</td>
                    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2012/09/26</td>
                    <td>$217,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>17</td>
                    <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                    <td>Development Lead</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2011/09/03</td>
                    <td>$345,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>57</td>
                    <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2009/06/25</td>
                    <td>$675,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2011/12/12</td>
                    <td>$106,450</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>2010/09/20</td>
                    <td>$85,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2009/10/09</td>
                    <td>$1,200,000</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

### javascript

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({  
    "language": {
    "paginate": {
      "previous": "<",
      "next": ">"
    }
  }
});
```

### style

```
.paginate_button {
margin-right:10px;

cursor:pointer;
}
.current{

}
.dataTables_paginate{
    float:right;
}
.previous{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
.next{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your triangles are `a` tags, defaulting to inline styling.
Try adding `display: inline-block`.

```
.previous{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
}
.next{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

I also edited the triangle css a bit (borders), not sure what exact shape you were going for but you can edit it pretty easily by just changing the sizes.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38zoxv48/7/)